# C  Bus Error: 10 bootstrap.sh

Tags: c

So while running this code I keep getting the error:

"/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/C.tmbundle/Support/bin/bootstrap.sh: line 7: 11441 Bus error: 10           "$3".out"

I looked through previous posts but couldn't figure it out, does anyone have an idea why this would be happening.  Ive seen posts saying it is because of the arrays being too large for memory but i can't imagine 2 20space int arrays are that big.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_file(int *x, int *y);

int main()
{
    int count, x[25], y[25];
    count = read_file(x,y);
    return 0;
}

int read_file(int *x, int *y)
{
    int number, i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    printf("File open");
    for(i = 0 ; fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) != 0; i++)
    {
            x[i] = number;
    }
    for(i = 0 ; fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) != 0; i++)
    {
        y[i] = number;
    }
        fclose(fp);
        return (i-1);
}
```

data.txt looks like:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 0

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 0

Comment: Just a couple tips, you might want to change `printf("File open");` to `printf("File open\n");`, and also consider checking that the return value of `fopen()` (`fp`) isn't null to ensure the file was actually opened.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`fscanf` returns the number of of items successfully read, I think you want to test if `number == 0` to break from the loop.

Comment: That's wrong!!!!  What if your input happens to be zero?!?!  One workaround is to test if `fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1`.  I'd strongly urge you to check "fopen()", too!

Comment: @paulsm4 `What if your input happens to be zero?` then you exit the loop, the number being zero is the end of a set of data

Comment: @Musa: detecting end-of-input using "number == 0" (a data value), instead of "fscanf()" (a status value) is a really, really poor choice.  It might happen to work for this particular data set... but why limit yourself??? Why waste an in-band value as a sentinel when you can use an out-of-band status "for free"???????

Answer (score 2):

fscanf can return EOF (-1?) if the input is bad - lets assume that isn't your problem.
What is stopping x reading all of the numbers? Looks like you mean to stop the loop when number == 0.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a print() (or run in the debugger) and see if the "for()" loop is really terminating where you think it is :)

You absolutely need to change your code to check for:

1. Error in "fopen()"
2. Error in "fscanf()"